# How do I hide lsp process messages in neovim?

Tags: configuration, neovim, liskov-substitution-principle

When using neovim with my lsp configurations, I have been getting these messages in right bottom corner of my screen that are really distracting while trying to code. If someone know's how to hide them pls let me know.[lsp message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrQA9.png)

I couldn't find any reference to those messages in the documentation.

Comment: These LSP notifications seem come from `fidget` plugin (https://github.com/j-hui/fidget.nvim). Do you install and use this plugin in your Neovim configuration ?

Comment: Yes, you were right. I first downloaded the kickstart.nvim without realizing it had this plugin, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

It might be the work of one of the plugins you have installed. You can check and edit the configuration file with the features you want and disable the rest of them.